# Update ProgressBar with a CountDownTimer

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-progressbar, countdowntimer

I'm trying to update a `ProgressBar` with `AsyncTask` and `CountDownTimer`. I have no errors but the `ProgressBar` is not updated.

Since `MyDownloadTask` extends `AsyncTask` I don't need the publish method or `onProgressUpdate()`. My ProgressBar is automatically updated in doInBackground().

I think the code in the `CountDownTimer` is not executed, but I am calling `monCountTimer.start();`

Here my Java code:

```
public class myDownloadTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, String> {
    public void setMonCountTimer(CountDownTimer monCountTimer) {
        this.monCountTimer = monCountTimer;
    }

    public void setInc(int inc) {
        this.inc = inc;
    }

    public void setMaProgressBar(ProgressBar maProgressBar) {
        this.maProgressBar = maProgressBar;
    }

    public CountDownTimer getMonCountTimer() {

        return monCountTimer;
    }

    public int getInc() {
        return inc;
    }

    public ProgressBar getMaProgressBar() {
        return maProgressBar;
    }

    protected CountDownTimer monCountTimer;
    private int inc = 0;
    protected ProgressBar maProgressBar;

    public void setMonAct(MainActivity monAct) {
        this.monAct = monAct;
    }

    public MainActivity getMonAct() {
        return monAct;
    }

    private MainActivity monAct;


    public myDownloadTask(ProgressBar maBarre, MainActivity monActi) {
        this.maProgressBar = maBarre;
        this.monAct = monActi;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        this.maProgressBar.setProgress(0);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... integers) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(integers);

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Integer... integers) {
        Thread monThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                monCountTimer = new CountDownTimer(6000, 1000) {
                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        myDownloadTask.this.inc++;
                        myDownloadTask.this.getMaProgressBar().setProgress((int) myDownloadTask.this.inc* 100 / (6000 / 1000));
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                    }

                };
                monCountTimer.start();
            }
        });
        return "coucou";
    }
}
```

The Main Class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    private ProgressBar maBarre ;

    public void setMaBarre(ProgressBar maBarre) {
        this.maBarre = maBarre;
    }

    public void setLaunchAsync(Button launchAsync) {
        this.launchAsync = launchAsync;
    }

    public void setMonHandler(Handler monHandler) {
        this.monHandler = monHandler;
    }

    public void setMonCountTimer(CountDownTimer monCountTimer) {
        this.monCountTimer = monCountTimer;
    }

    public void setMonTask(myDownloadTask monTask) {
        this.monTask = monTask;
    }

    public void setProgressThread(Thread progressThread) {
        ProgressThread = progressThread;
    }

    public void setI(int i) {

        this.i = i;
    }

    public ProgressBar getMaBarre() {

        return maBarre;
    }

    public Button getLaunchAsync() {
        return launchAsync;
    }

    public Handler getMonHandler() {
        return monHandler;
    }

    public CountDownTimer getMonCountTimer() {
        return monCountTimer;
    }

    public String getPROGRESS_BAR_INCREMENT() {
        return PROGRESS_BAR_INCREMENT;
    }

    public static int getMessagePreExecute() {
        return MESSAGE_PRE_EXECUTE;
    }

    public static int getMessageProgressUpdate() {
        return MESSAGE_PROGRESS_UPDATE;
    }

    public static int getMessagePostExecute() {
        return MESSAGE_POST_EXECUTE;
    }

    public myDownloadTask getMonTask() {
        return monTask;
    }

    public Thread getProgressThread() {
        return ProgressThread;
    }

    public int getI() {
        return i;
    }

    private Button launchAsync;
    private Handler monHandler ;
    private CountDownTimer monCountTimer ;

    private final String PROGRESS_BAR_INCREMENT="ProgreesBarIncrementId";
    private static final int MESSAGE_PRE_EXECUTE = 1;
    private static final int MESSAGE_PROGRESS_UPDATE = 2;
    private static final int MESSAGE_POST_EXECUTE = 3;
    myDownloadTask monTask;
    Thread ProgressThread ;
    private int i = 0 ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        maBarre = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        launchAsync = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        this.launchAsync.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                monTask = new myDownloadTask(MainActivity.this.maBarre , MainActivity.this);
                monTask.execute();
             
                }
        });

    }



 
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
    }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    public void onPointerCaptureChanged(boolean hasCapture) {

    }

}
```

Could you help me please?

Comment: Hi. I'll try to help. It would be good to provide a little more analysis about what might be wrong. Also, it would good to post the xml layout. But the first thing to do is to chop the problem in half. Is it a presentation problem? Or is it problem in the logic that updates the progress bar? If for example 'maBarre.setProgress(50)' is added to onCreate does the progress bar appear on the screen?

Comment: Okay. It is best to edit the original question with any additional info. Don't post it in the answer until a solution  has been found. If you post code in the answer then you're going to get downvoted which will reduce the probability of getting a useful response since less people see downvoted questions. Did you do what I suggested? Try call setProgress(50) in onCreate to verify that the progress appears on the screen? If it doesn't appear then it is mostly likely a layout problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for your XML file. I don't know what layout you're trying to achieve, but when I did "setProgress(50);" in onCreate, nothing appeared using the XML file that was posted.

I created this XML layout instead, now the progress bar appears fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/progressBar" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="10dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

In onCreate, add:

```
ProgressBar bar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
bar.setProgress(50);
```

to test the layout...

A few more problems: The thread has been created but start() must be called afterwards.

```
 monCountTimer.start();
```

In public void run(), the code is doing:

```
  myDownloadTask.this.getMaProgressBar().setProgress((int) 
    myDownloadTask.this.inc* 100 / (6000 / 1000));
```

Never update views from a worker thread in Android. All views must be updated on the "Main Thread" also known as the "UI thread"

A quick way to solve this would be to do:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // ...
    }
});
```

I've made the changes above, now it runs fine:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    private ProgressBar maBarre ;

    public void setMaBarre(ProgressBar maBarre) {
        this.maBarre = maBarre;
    }

    public void setLaunchAsync(Button launchAsync) {
        this.launchAsync = launchAsync;
    }

    public void setMonHandler(Handler monHandler) {
        this.monHandler = monHandler;
    }

    public void setMonCountTimer(CountDownTimer monCountTimer) {
        this.monCountTimer = monCountTimer;
    }

    public void setMonTask(myDownloadTask monTask) {
        this.monTask = monTask;
    }

    public void setProgressThread(Thread progressThread) {
        ProgressThread = progressThread;
    }

    public void setI(int i) {

        this.i = i;
    }

    public ProgressBar getMaBarre() {

        return maBarre;
    }

    public Button getLaunchAsync() {
        return launchAsync;
    }

    public Handler getMonHandler() {
        return monHandler;
    }

    public CountDownTimer getMonCountTimer() {
        return monCountTimer;
    }

    public String getPROGRESS_BAR_INCREMENT() {
        return PROGRESS_BAR_INCREMENT;
    }

    public static int getMessagePreExecute() {
        return MESSAGE_PRE_EXECUTE;
    }

    public static int getMessageProgressUpdate() {
        return MESSAGE_PROGRESS_UPDATE;
    }

    public static int getMessagePostExecute() {
        return MESSAGE_POST_EXECUTE;
    }

    public myDownloadTask getMonTask() {
        return monTask;
    }

    public Thread getProgressThread() {
        return ProgressThread;
    }

    public int getI() {
        return i;
    }

    private Button launchAsync;
    private Handler monHandler ;
    private CountDownTimer monCountTimer ;

    private final String PROGRESS_BAR_INCREMENT="ProgreesBarIncrementId";
    private static final int MESSAGE_PRE_EXECUTE = 1;
    private static final int MESSAGE_PROGRESS_UPDATE = 2;
    private static final int MESSAGE_POST_EXECUTE = 3;
    myDownloadTask monTask;
    Thread ProgressThread ;
    private int i = 0 ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        maBarre = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        launchAsync = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        //etSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        this.launchAsync.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                monTask = new myDownloadTask(MainActivity.this.maBarre , MainActivity.this);
                monTask.execute();

            }
        });

    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    public void onPointerCaptureChanged(boolean hasCapture) {

    }


    public class myDownloadTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, String> {
        public void setMonCountTimer(CountDownTimer monCountTimer) {
            this.monCountTimer = monCountTimer;
        }

        public void setInc(int inc) {
            this.inc = inc;
        }

        public void setMaProgressBar(ProgressBar maProgressBar) {
            this.maProgressBar = maProgressBar;
        }

        public CountDownTimer getMonCountTimer() {

            return monCountTimer;
        }

        public int getInc() {
            return inc;
        }

        public ProgressBar getMaProgressBar() {
            return maProgressBar;
        }

        protected CountDownTimer monCountTimer;
        private int inc = 0;
        protected ProgressBar maProgressBar;

        public void setMonAct(MainActivity monAct) {
            this.monAct = monAct;
        }

        public MainActivity getMonAct() {
            return monAct;
        }

        private MainActivity monAct;


        public myDownloadTask(ProgressBar maBarre, MainActivity monActi) {
            this.maProgressBar = maBarre;
            this.monAct = monActi;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            this.maProgressBar.setProgress(0);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... integers) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(integers);

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Integer... integers) {
            Thread monThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            monCountTimer = new CountDownTimer(6000, 1000) {
                                @Override
                                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                                    myDownloadTask.this.inc++;
                                    myDownloadTask.this.getMaProgressBar().setProgress((int) myDownloadTask.this.inc * 100 / (6000 / 1000));
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onFinish() {
                                }

                            };
                            monCountTimer.start();

                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            monThread.start();
            return "coucou";
        }
    }
}
```

A few issues to think about:

- There are more threads being created here than what's need, the code could be written more simply. doInBackground is already on a separate thread so there is no need to create another thread in there. Also, I believe CountDownTimer already runs in its own thread so probably a lot of the code here is unnecessary.
- When you're done developing, get rid of all those warnings. Software development is really about discipline and good habbits, only bad developers ignore the warnings! Do a "analyze -> inspect code" when you're done.

But your progress bar updater works fine for me now.

Comment: ok thanks you very much .I think that i developped the same program 1 year ago , but strangely i didn't need runOnUi  runOnUiThread() .It was my main difficult here

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />





</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Please provide a single explained solution. Or make sure that each of your solutions is fundamentally different that the others and makes obvious in which way.  I get the impression that you should add info to the question instead of these unexplained code-dumps....

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

            <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="236dp"
            android:text="Button"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/progressBar"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/progressBar"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="336dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="104dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I think that the problem is concerned the Thread ,without AsyncTask ,it 's work but it is not propely .I think so , i forget the instruction monThread.start().But with this instruction ,my application  doesn't work when i touch the button

Comment: See the answer I just posted. The XML layout did not display the progress bar in the emulator.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks you very much !!!!!:))

i have tried :

```
   @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Integer... integers) {
        Thread monThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                monCountTimer = new CountDownTimer(6000, 1000) {
                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        myDownloadTask.this.inc++;
                        myDownloadTask.this.getMaProgressBar().setProgress((int) myDownloadTask.this.inc* 100 / (6000 / 1000));
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                    }

                };
                monCountTimer.start();
            }
            monThread.start();

        });
        return "coucou";
    }
```

with this code my application has just been crashed.

But with  `runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {....}` it's work

We use 2 Threads ...;( it is not optimized and 3 with monCountTimer , maybe , we could remove `monThread`

"I believe CountDownTimer already runs in its own thread so probably a lot of the code here is unnecessary."

I 've tried :

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Integer... integers) {
    monCountTimer = new CountDownTimer(6000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        myDownloadTask.this.inc++;
        myDownloadTask.this.getMaProgressBar().setProgress((int) myDownloadTask.this.inc * 100 / (6000 / 1000));
    }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
    }

    };
    monCountTimer.start();
}
```

and it doesn't work

Comment: Okay, but please stop posting more solutions...It is fine just to make a comment on the solution that I've already posted. It works fine in my environment so I'm not sure what to tell you. You'll have to give me something more go than simply it doesn't work. Any errors in the logs? Try cutting and pasting my file in your project. I just merged all your code into 1 class to make it quicker to work on, but it should run as is...Use my XML file as well...G'Luck.

Comment: yes i did it , i tested your code yesterday , but we have to create much threads ,this is i would to explain and to use runOnUiThread() i can't separate my two class , for the myDownloadAsyncTask Class

Comment: This does not seem to be an answer to the question. More like additional info which should be edited into the question.